# Confusing word usages in "Pasttime Paradise"

Tags: word-usage

Today I came accross an old song on the radio, "Pasttime paradise", and decided to pay attention to the lyrics. I had a little hard time to understand the logic behind some words.

I'm hoping to understand what they really mean.

```
Dissipation
Race Relations
Consolation 
Segregation 
Dispensation 
Isolation 
Exploitation 
Mutilation 
Mutations 
Miscreation 
Confirmation.......to the evils of the world
```

And on the second cycle

```
Proclamation of Race Relations 
Consolation 
Integration 
Verification of Revelations 
Acclamation 
World Salvation 
Vibrations 
Simulation 
Confirmation.......to the peace of the world
```

What I am really missing here is, few words have been used in both of evil and peaceful contexts.

> Consolation
>
> Confirmation

I am having trouble to see the meaning behind it.

Also, it's more interesting to me the usage of phrase:

> Race Relations

Isn't it a good thing? Author using it while listing the evils of the world got me confused.

Or does this mean the author is against the `Race Relations`?

If someone can shed light on these, that would be great.

Comment: Who knows what the particular logic, if any, the songwriter meant, or how that relates to any sort of logic a particular listener wants to apply to the lyrics. This is similar to literary criticism  which is off-topic.

Comment: Think this is an ELL question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if you are asking for a definition of a word, that is general reference and, moreover, explanations of song lyrics are off-topic for EL&U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of **'Race Relations'** in the first verse - this was written at a time when race relations were poor - any mention of the phrase generally had negative connotations - if you brought it up in conversation, it's probably because you were going to speak about problems with race relations rather than anything good!

**'Consolation'** can mean to console or comfort somebody who is upset, usually after a loss.

**'Confirmation'** has a religious context - somewhat like 'baptism'. Stevie Wonder frequently uses religious allusions in his songs, it is not unreasonable to read this as religious in this example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation